# How can I optimize the weight of SVG images generated using Apache Batik?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I have written the following code using Apache Batik in order to generate SVG images ([full source available on GitHub](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-status/blob/master/src/main/java/com/qualinsight/plugins/sonarqube/status/internal/SVGImageGenerator.java)) representing badges showing if code passes a SonarQube quality gate or not:

```
private SVGGraphics2D generateFor(final QualityGateStatus status) {
    // new SVG graphics
    final SVGGraphics2D svgGraphics2D = new SVGGraphics2D(this.svgGeneratorContext, false);
    // set SVG canvas size
    svgGraphics2D.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(LABEL_WIDTH + status.displayWidth(), CANVAS_HEIGHT));
    // set font
    svgGraphics2D.setFont(FONT_FAMILY);
    // draw Label background
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_BACKGROUND_LABEL);
    svgGraphics2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, LABEL_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER);
    svgGraphics2D.fillRect(LABEL_WIDTH - BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, 0, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    // draw Label text shadow
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_SHADOW);
    svgGraphics2D.drawString(LABEL_TEXT, X_MARGIN, Y_OFFSET_SHADOW);
    // draw Label text
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_TEXT);
    svgGraphics2D.drawString(LABEL_TEXT, X_MARGIN, Y_OFFSET_TEXT);
    // draw result background
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(status.displayBackgroundColor());
    svgGraphics2D.fillRoundRect(LABEL_WIDTH, 0, status.displayWidth(), CANVAS_HEIGHT, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER);
    svgGraphics2D.fillRect(LABEL_WIDTH, 0, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
    // draw result text shadow
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_SHADOW);
    svgGraphics2D.drawString(status.displayText(), LABEL_WIDTH + X_MARGIN, 15);
    // draw result text
    svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_TEXT);
    svgGraphics2D.drawString(status.displayText(), LABEL_WIDTH + X_MARGIN, 14);
    return svgGraphics2D;
}
```

Examples of produced images (depending on parameters passed to the `generateFor()` method) can be seen on [GitHub as well](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-status/tree/master/images).

This code works fine, however currently the weight of a generated image is more or less 2KB, which is almost 3 times heavier than travis-ci badges that weight more or less 700 Bytes. Therefor I have the feeling that generated images could be simplified, sized down to ~1KB.

How can I achieve this using Apache Batik ? Should I use another library or use another approach ?

Thanks in advance for your insight and recommendations !

Comment: You can try this online SVG optimizer .. https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/  .. it has lots of options to choose from to tweak the file size of your SVG Image .. you can either copy and paste it or open it as a file for it to optimize

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My SVG images are generated on the fly then cached. Therefore I cant use an online optimiser. I need to be able to find a way to optimise them on server side and at runtime.

Comment: Have you also tried enabling `gzip` to your SVG files when delivered .. http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2014/tips-for-optimising-svg-delivery-for-the-web/

Answer (score 2):

I tried generating your SVG using [JFreeSVG 3.0](https://github.com/jfree/jfreesvg), and with the GZIP option it creates files around 570 bytes.  In plain text the SVG is around 1.7 kbytes.

Here is the test program I ran (based on your code, you'll also need your QualityGateStatus class to run this):

```
/*
 * qualinsight-plugins-sonarqube-status
 * Copyright (c) 2015, QualInsight
 * http://www.qualinsight.com/
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either
 * version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this program. If not, you can retrieve a copy
 * from <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGGraphics2D;
import org.jfree.graphics2d.svg.SVGUtils;

public final class SVGImageGenerator {

    private static final int FONT_SIZE = 11;

    private static final Font FONT_FAMILY = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE);

    private static final int X_MARGIN = 4;

    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 20;

    private static final int LABEL_WIDTH = 46;

    private static final String LABEL_TEXT = "quality";

    private static final int BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER = 6;

    private static final Color COLOR_BACKGROUND_LABEL = new Color(85, 85, 85, 255);

    private static final Color COLOR_SHADOW = new Color(0, 0, 0, 85);

    private static final Color COLOR_TEXT = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);

    private static final int Y_OFFSET_SHADOW = 14;

    private static final int Y_OFFSET_TEXT = 14;


    private static String generateFor(final QualityGateStatus status) {
        // new SVG graphics
        final SVGGraphics2D svgGraphics2D = new SVGGraphics2D(LABEL_WIDTH + status.displayWidth(), CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        // set font
        svgGraphics2D.setFont(FONT_FAMILY);
        // draw Label background
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_BACKGROUND_LABEL);
        svgGraphics2D.fillRoundRect(0, 0, LABEL_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER);
        svgGraphics2D.fillRect(LABEL_WIDTH - BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, 0, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        // draw Label text shadow
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_SHADOW);
        svgGraphics2D.drawString(LABEL_TEXT, X_MARGIN, Y_OFFSET_SHADOW);
        // draw Label text
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_TEXT);
        svgGraphics2D.drawString(LABEL_TEXT, X_MARGIN, Y_OFFSET_TEXT);
        // draw result background
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(status.displayBackgroundColor());
        svgGraphics2D.fillRoundRect(LABEL_WIDTH, 0, status.displayWidth(), CANVAS_HEIGHT, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER);
        svgGraphics2D.fillRect(LABEL_WIDTH, 0, BACKGROUND_CORNER_ARC_DIAMETER, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        // draw result text shadow
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_SHADOW);
        svgGraphics2D.drawString(status.displayText(), LABEL_WIDTH + X_MARGIN, 15);
        // draw result text
        svgGraphics2D.setColor(COLOR_TEXT);
        svgGraphics2D.drawString(status.displayText(), LABEL_WIDTH + X_MARGIN, 14);
        return svgGraphics2D.getSVGElement();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SVGUtils.writeToSVG(new File("error.svgz"), generateFor(QualityGateStatus.ERROR), true);
            SVGUtils.writeToSVG(new File("none.svgz"), generateFor(QualityGateStatus.NONE), true);
            SVGUtils.writeToSVG(new File("ok.svgz"), generateFor(QualityGateStatus.OK), true);
            SVGUtils.writeToSVG(new File("server_error.svgz"), generateFor(QualityGateStatus.SERVER_ERROR), true);
            SVGUtils.writeToSVG(new File("warn.svgz"), generateFor(QualityGateStatus.WARN), true);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, svgz is not an option as I cannot set the HTTP response headers (limitation of SonarQube, and the development team considers my usecase as being a not good enough reason for adding the ability to set headers manualy...) However, if I can lower the size of my svgs by 15%  as your post suggests it, I'll have a look at JFreeSVG, thanks !

Comment: Your library is interesting, however it is licensed under GPL and I want to stick to LGPL (using your library would force me to move to GPL if I'm not wrong).

Comment: Yes, you are right.  Thanks for paying attention to licensing, so many developers ignore it (surprisingly).